# How does jQuery make the returned value look like an array?

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(); //[]
jQuery("#footer"); //[<div id="footer">...</div>]
```

I know that you can do something like this:

```
function kablam(tag) {
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    els.isKablam = true;
    return els;
}
var body = kablam("body"); //[<body class="ask-page">...</body>]
body.isKablam; //true
```

To return an "extended" version of the [`NodeList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1938918D) that's returned from `document.getElementsByTagName`.

However, jQuery does the opposite. It merges the result into itself (as can be seen [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L142) and [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L188)). Furthermore, that doesn't explain how it returns an array-like-object-that-looks-like-an-array when you pass nothing to it:

```
jQuery(); //[]
```

When you do that, jQuery simply returns itself. ([source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L84))

Or to the same extend, when you select the body tag:

```
jQuery("body"); //[<body class="ask-page">...</body>]
```

([source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L96))

Or, come to think of it, anything at all:

```
var o = {}, body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
jQuery.merge(o, body); //Object, not [...]
```

Returning array-like objects is super easy, since assigning numeric keys is trivial and no different than assigning any other key. But how does jQuery make it "look like" an array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define `.length`, `.splice` and `.push` on a prototype for it display like an array.

Some other combination of array methods may also work.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/f58e3/9/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure `.push` isn't needed :)

Comment: Also, it doesn't need to be on the prototype. Try this in the console: `a={length:0, splice:function(){}}`

Answer (score 0):

What is "look like an array" in your opinion? How would you check for arrayness? If you consider everything that has a length to be an array then all you need to make an object looks like array is to define the length property. jQuery do that.

Comment: That's why I separated array-like and array-look-alike. Array-like is considered to have a length and numeric indexes (both of which are trivial to do). The shortest answer for array-look-alike is that when you log it, you think you're looking at an array.

Comment: @bjornd in this case "looks like an array" means the debugger/console/dev-tools in browsers print it as an array

Comment: @Zirak, @Raynos So it solely depends on how debugger/console/dev-tools handle types of objects. For example they can check for `object instanceof Array` or check for length or another array-specific property.

Comment: @bjornd When you do `jQuery()`, the only thing the result has in common with your average array is the `.length` property. If it is dependent on the debugger/whatever, what are the conditions?